# How to remove data folder as well as part postgres9.1 uninstall script forcefully

Tags: linux, shell, uninstallation

Can anyone please suggest me that how I can remove data directory forecefully as part of uninstall script of postgres.

This is the script I invoked under postgres installed directory to uninstall the postgres.

**./uninstall-postgresql**

Currently we are getting the warning message like **The data directory(/opt/DB/data) and service user account(postgres) have not been removed.**

Comment: Update the script. Or better, wrap the script is your own script which removes the data directory and user after the postgres uninstall script is finished.

Comment: Hi isedev, am not getting what you are saying here.But, from my understanding I can remove the data directory by rm -rf. But, here my question is that is there any options to remove data directory.

Comment: while using the ./uninstall-postgresql(Here we have any options as an arguments to remove forcefully)

Answer (score 0):

Try `./uninstall-postgresql --help` and `./uninstall-postgresql help` to see if there are any options to it (preferably as a user which wouldn't be able to *actually* uninstall it, to avoid disaster). If not, you simply have to add the commands to the script yourself.